# How to Completely Remove Archive Title a.k.a the_archive_title?

Tags: archives, archive-template

I want to remove it COMPLETELY. Not only the label "Archive: " but EVERYTHING. It should not appear. I've been looking for the solution for hours to no avail.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: So the page should render as `<title></title>`?

Comment: You need to remove it from the template, that's it.

Comment: @kero if i remove it, are my title tag gonna be empty? I just want to remove the `<h1>Archive: Bla3</h1>` not removing the title tag, is it possible?

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you please elaborate in answer, i'm not familiar with removing it from template.. thank you mate. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I'm adding this code in my theme's / child theme's function.php

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', 'my_get_the_archive_title' );
function my_get_the_archive_title( $title ) {
    return '';
};
```

And voilà it's gone, completely, forever!! Just the way I want it!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following function in the functions.php of your child theme.

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', 'my_get_the_archive_title' );
function my_get_the_archive_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Welcome vikrant! Thanks for your answer. One note is that it's better to not to use anonymous functions in answers as not everyone is using PHP > 5.3.0. I know they *should* be using current versions, but not everyone does so it can be confusing for some.  Also, it's a good practice to add some explanation to *why* your answer resolves the question - something a little more than "add this" gives the poster *and* future readers more relevant information.

Comment: AFAIK this only remove the "Archive: " or "Category: " before the archive. Not the archive completely. It doesn't remove archive title for custom post type too...